# Ajax Datatables from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

Hi I have just followed Ryan Bates guide to loading data from the server as the client interacts with the datatable.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast

In his ProductsDatatable class he defines a sorting function:

```
  def sort_column
    columns = %w[name category released_on price]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end
```

Basically the column name is used to query the database, so "name", "category", etc are all attributes to the product model.  So an SQL SELECT statement is generated with Name or Category being used for sorting ASC or DESC.. and so on...

If I have data being displayed in a column that does not map explicitly to a attribute.. such as product.reviews.count, how would I then allow sorting of that column?

Comment: #Abram I have the same issue, but I'm not seeing how to implement the answer.  Do you have a working sample to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something like this

```
def sort_column
    columns = ['name', 'category', 'released_on,' 'price', 'number_of_reviews]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end
```

But this means that you need to change the way you get your data, for example:

```
Product.where(…).select('name, category, count(reviews.id) as number_of_reviews').group('name, category').includes('reviews')
```

I haven't been able to test the definition of `columns`, you may have to use `reviews.number_of reviews` instead

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think it will probably work, but I got hung up almost immediately.. Instead of product I'm using 'style' >> Style Load (0.6ms)  SELECT count(reviews.id) as num_reviews FROM "styles" 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "reviews"
LINE 1: SELECT count(reviews.id) as num_reviews FROM "styles"

Comment: the log says "missing from-clause" entry for table 'reviews'. So you need to add that in your selection: chain `includes(:reviews)` just before or after your `where` statement

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post (by now), but just wanted to let you know that this gem: https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails can help you jumpstart creating datatables classes easily, as described in the Railscast you mention (it's actually based in this same pattern).

What the gem does is to let you focus on writing the query to retrieve your model(s) data from the db and how to expose it in the JSON that `jquery.dataTables` needs.

Take it for a spin.